# SSD for Asus N552VX laptop

Tags: laptop, ssd

[Asus N552VX](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/VivoBook-Pro-N552VX/specifications/) laptop comes with a hard disk. To make it faster I replaced the hard disk with [Adata Ultimate SU800](http://www.adata.com/en/specification/410) SSD(SATA connection) and attached the mechanical hard disk replacing optical disk drive. Now the problem is normally laptop got faster, but OS(Windows 10) loads slowly than hard disk in ssd which is very unusual. There is no problem in the SSD itself, because I have tested this SSD in other laptop which works fine.Problem occur only with the above mentioned Asus laptop. N.B. this Asus laptop has M.2 port and this. Now I want to use a M.2 SSD with this but I'm fearing that will same problem be occurred with M.2 SSD. So please recommend a M.2 SSD which will be compatible with this laptop.

Config:
Intel Core i5-6300HQ
Motherboard Chipset: Intel HM170 (Skylake PCH-H)
2 sticks of DDR4 4GB RAM (SK Hynix)
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M
Intel HD Graphics 530
TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 1TB HDD

BIOS details:
BIOS Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
BIOS Version: N552VX.207
BIOS Release Date: 02/04/2016
BIOS Start Segment: F000
BIOS Size: 6016 KBytes

Comment: I looked up the spec sheet for the SU800 and it doesn't seem that bad. Can you post the exact specs of your laptop so we can best recommend an upgrade for you? The data sheet your provided shows all possible configurations for your laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the spec sheet and model number that you provided, and [this review](https://laptopmedia.com/review/asus-n552vx-review-not-the-update-weve-expected-but-adds-some-essential-features/) it looks to me like any optional M.2 PCIe NVMe 2280 SSD should work. Crucial lists several if you expand [the list.](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/ASUS/n552vw) It never hurts to double check with the manufacturer regarding any limitations inherent in **your particular model**.

I would be remiss if I didn't note an SSD should never be as slow as a hard drive and that this is truly the result that you are getting, something is most definitely wrong (possibly your testing methodology) as the Toshiba MQ01ABD100 is a 5400 RPM drive and the [benchmarks](http://hdd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/784/TOSHIBA-MQ01ABD100) are less than stellar and the Adata you linked to on it's worst day should [benchmark much faster](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Adata-Ultimate-SU800-128GB-vs-Adata-Ultimate-SU800-256GB/3911vs3912).